# Traducir una consulta SQL con subconsulta a CAML

Tags: sharepoint

Quiero crear una consulta `CAML` a partir de una consulta `SQL`. La consulta `SQL` contiene una subconsulta de la misma lista.

Lo he intentado de mil maneras pero no funciona.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
select * from "list" where NameUser = (select NameUser from "list" where responsable = [Me])
```

> El campo -Responsable-  es del tipo usuario y el campo -NameUser- es
>   de tipo cadena.

Comment: Te recomiendo que montes el resultado esperado en una vista de una lista de `SharePoint`, luego por medio del `SharePoint Designer` ingreses a esa vista, ubiques el código `CAML` de la vista (el `QUERY`) y ya con eso obtienes la estructura necesaria del `CAML`, luego trata de montar esa misma estructura en el resultado del `SELECT`.

Comment: Sí, también pensé eso, pero es imposible crear una vista que muestre lo que busco a partir de funcionalidad de Sharepoint 2013, ya que sólo me permite hacer consultas anidadas de tipo Y / O.

Answer (score 0):

Las consultas CALM definen los tipos de datos string de una manera y los tipos sp user Usuario mediante el id del ususario. Tienes que saber el id del usuario . si es el ususario logado o si fuera otro el id que tiene ese usuario en la colección de sitios donde trabajas

algo asi como

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='User' />
    <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
```